# d3.js bundle layout, moving nodes inklusiv line

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'd like to move a selected node in a bundle layout and redraw the line.

Do you have any suggestions how I could solve that problem?

First I tried to move the node via translate:

```
node.attr("transform", function (nodeObject) {
        var translationValue = nodeObject.y         
        return "rotate(" + (nodeObject.x - 90) + ")translate(" + (nodeObject.y + 20) + ")";
    })
```

But uf course if I try to move the line that way I won't get anywhere. It will just move the whole line and I can't control the endpoints.

I've tried to remove all lines and redraw them. But the connections will point to the original point not to moved ones.

```
var line = d3.svg.line.radial()
    .interpolate("bundle")
    .tension(.75)
    .radius(function (d) {
        return d.y;
    })
    .angle(function (d) {
        return d.x / 180 * Math.PI;
    });

vis.selectAll("path.link").remove();

vis.selectAll("path.link")
    .data(bundle(links))
    .enter().append("path")
    .each(function (d3Object) {
        d3Object.source = d3Object[0], d3Object.target = d3Object[d3Object.length - 1];
    })
    .attr("d", line);
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manipulate the line attributes and redraw the line.

```
link.transition()
    .attr("d",
    function(d, i) {
        if (d.target === d3Object || d.source === d3Object) {
            line.radius(function (d) {
                return d.y - 51;
            });
            line.angle(function (d) {
                return d.x / 180 * Math.PI;
            });
        } else {
            line.radius(function (d) {
                return d.y;
            });
            line.angle(function (d) {
                return d.x / 180 * Math.PI;
            });
        }

        return line(splines[i]);
    })
    .duration(1500);
```